# Replace values within a column if a certain condition is met using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to map values based on a specific condition and override the values that are in an existing column.

**Data**

```
ID  Date    Location    Used  Status
AA  Q121    NY          20    ok
AA  Q221    NY          50    ok
AA  Q321    NY          10    ok
BB  Q121    CA          1     ok
BB  Q221    CA          0     yes
BB  Q321    CA          500   yes
BB  Q421    CA          700   no
CC  Q121    AZ          50    no
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    Location    Used    Status
AA  Q121    NY                  closed
AA  Q221    NY                  closed
AA  Q321    NY                  closed
BB  Q121    CA          1       ok
BB  Q221    CA          0       yes
BB  Q321    CA          500     yes
BB  Q421    CA          700     no
CC  Q121    AZ          50      no
```

**Doing**

```
df['Used'] = np.where(((df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121')), '', df['Used'])
df['Status'] = np.where(((df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121')), 'closed', '')
```

The script above replaces 'ok' with 'closed' , however, it also deletes the remaining values in the column.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
df.loc[(df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121'), 'Used'] = ''
df.loc[(df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121'), 'Status'] = 'closed'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df['ID'].eq('AA')) & (df['Date'] >= 'Q121'), 'Status'] = 'closed'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer using np.where as stated in the question:

```
d = {
    'ID': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'],
    'Date': ['Q121', 'Q221', 'Q321', 'Q121', 'Q221'],
    'Location': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA'],
    'Used': [20, 50, 10, 1, 0],
    'Status': ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'yes']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

idx = np.where((df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121'))[0].tolist()

df.loc[idx, 'Used'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx, 'Status'] = 'Closed'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply for this:

```
df['Used'],df['Status'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: ('', 'closed') if (x.ID == 'AA') and (x.Date >= 'Q121') else (x.Used, x.Status), axis = 1))
```